# Jenkins - can the “Execute Shell” execute SSH commands

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh

I use 'Execute Shell' to run below command in Jenkins, but nothing happened in the remote server

```
ssh -v baiming.zhang@192.168.0.47 'pybot.bat --argumentfile E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目\logs\argfile.txt E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目'
```

below are the output of the Jenkins

[image]

Comment: There should not be any problems with running SSH commands in a shell. I have done that between different Unix-based servers without any problems. In your log it also seems your ssh login is successful and that it is actually sending the command. If you would run the full ssh command from a shell (outside Jenkins) will it work then?

Comment: the command works fine from a shell(outside Jenkins), but it does not work well in Jenkins, the Jenkins is running on Linux and the remote server a Windows

Comment: Does the same apply if you use the command listed that it is sending in your log? The command looks different from when you are invoking the shell compared to what it is sending, which I assume is due to character conversion of some kind. Just to eliminate possible causes. (If you would paste your log as text rather than an image then I can copy in exactly what I mean).

Comment: @DanielBarbarian the command and the log is matched, below is partail of the log: debug1: Sending command: pybot.bat --argumentfile E:\\project\\robot_framework\\\347\254\254\344\270\200\344\270\252\346\265\213\350\257\225\351\241\271\347\233\256\\logs\\argfile.txt E:\\project\\robot_framework\\\347\254\254\344\270\200\344\270\252\346\265\213\350\257\225\351\241\271\347\233\256

Comment: Ok, if that is what you have tried then I am a bit out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Double quote (") to execute the commands on remote system.

ssh -v baiming.zhang@192.168.0.47 "pybot.bat --argumentfile E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目\logs\argfile.txt E:\project\robot_framework\第一个测试项目"